# Discrepancy between Data in save() callback and Database

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I am working on a multiplayer card game in sails.js and am running into an issue concerning save(). I am querying for 3 records, making changes to their a few of their association attributes, then saving them sequentially. The problem is that the temp copy of the saved data passed as a parameter to the function passed to save(cb), is different than the information on the database.

I am using two relevant models: Cards, which have an 'attachments' attribute, that is a collection of card records, and Players, which have 'hand' and 'runes' attributes, which are both collections of card records.

The action takes the following parameters:

req.body.thiefId and req.body.victimId are the id's of Player records.
req.body.jackId and req.body.targetId are the id's of Card records.

req.body.pNum is the index of the thief player after the players are sorted. sortPlayers[req.body.pNum] is the thief player and sortPlayers[(req.body.pNum + 1) % 2] is the victim player.

The action takes a jack out of the thief's hand, puts it into the attachments collection of the target card (which begins in the victim player's runes collection), removes the target card from the victim player's runes collection and adds the target card to the thief player's runes collection. Then the records are all saved. Essentially, the jack is played from one player's (the thief's) hand, 'on top' of a card in the victim player's runes, and then the target card is moved to the thief's runes.

The problem is that the 'runes' attributes of both players are not being properly persisted on the database. Whichever player is the victim keeps the target card in their runes collection and the the thief player does not add the target card to their runes collection. The jack card is properly removed from the hand collection of the thief player and added to the attachments of the target card. What is really odd is that the local copy of the data returned by save() is correct! The records savedP0 and savedP1 always have the correct rune collections, but checking the server at localhost:1337/player reveals that the database has not persisted the changes. How is this possible? My understanding of the save() method is that the record parameter passed to the function that is passed to save() is always an exact copy of what the database actually recorded.

Here is a relatively minimalistic example of the action causing the problem:

```
    jackBug: function (req, res) {
        Player.find([req.body.thiefId, req.body.victimId]).populateAll().exec(function (erro, players) {
            Card.findOne(req.body.targetId).populate('attachments').exec(function (err, targetCard) {
                //Sort the players according to their 'pNum' attribute
                var playerSort = sortPlayers(players);

                //Remove the jack from the theif player's hand and add the target card to the thief player's points
                playerSort[req.body.pNum].runes.add(targetCard.id);
                playerSort[req.body.pNum].hand.remove(req.body.jackId);

                //Remove the target card from the victim player's points
                playerSort[(req.body.pNum + 1) % 2].runes.remove(targetCard.id);

                //Add the jack card to the target card's attachments
                targetCard.attachments.add(req.body.jackId);


                    playerSort[0].save(function (e, savedP0) {
                        playerSort[1].save(function (e6, savedP1) {
                            targetCard.save(function(e7, savedTarget) {
                                console.log("\nsavedP0:");
                                //This data is always correct, even though the server is wrong
                                console.log(savedP0);
                                console.log("\n\nsavedP1");
                                //This data is also always correct, but it also disagrees with the server
                                console.log(savedP1);
                            });
                        });
                    });
            });
    });
},
```

What is happening? How can the database disagree with the record passed to the save() cb?

EDIT: Here is a refactored version of the action, which does not make a call to sortPLayer(players), in the hopes of avoiding issues with asynchronicity. The records returned to the cb's passed to save()'s are still correct and the database is still wrong.

```
    jackBug: function (req, res) {
        Player.find([req.body.thiefId, req.body.victimId]).populateAll().exec(function (erro, players) {
            Card.findOne(req.body.targetId).populate('attachments').exec(function (err, targetCard) {

                if (players[0].id === req.body.thiefId) {
                    var thiefIndex = 0;
                    var victimIndex = 1;
                } else if (players[1].id === req.body.thiefId) {
                    var thiefIndex = 1;
                    var victimIndex = 0;
                }

                //Remove the jack from the theif player's hand and add the target card to the thief player's points
                players[thiefIndex].runes.add(targetCard.id);
                players[thiefIndex].hand.remove(req.body.jackId);

                //Remove the target card from the victim player's runes
                players[victimIndex].runes.remove(targetCard.id);

                //Add the jack card to the target card's attachments
                targetCard.attachments.add(req.body.jackId);


                    players[0].save(function (e, savedP0) {
                        players[1].save(function (e6, savedP1) {
                            targetCard.save(function(e7, savedTarget) {
                                console.log("\nsavedP0:");
                                console.log(savedP0);
                                console.log("\n\nsavedP1");
                                console.log(savedP1);
                            });
                        });
                    });
            });
    });
},
```

Comment: Well, at fast look I can see only some async issues. Looks like `var playerSort = sortPlayers(players);` and `playerSort[0].save(function (e, savedP0) {}` are working in parrallel

Comment: If I understand your point correctly, it is that the sortPlayers(players) call and the save() are run in the same scope and that since save() is an asynchronous function, it may not be executing at the proper time? I have refactored the action to avoid using sortPlayers() at all, by using
'     if (players[0].id === req.body.thiefId) {
      var thiefIndex = 0;
      var victimIndex = 1;
     }'
to assign index variables and referring to the thief player as players[thiefIndex] and the victim player as players[victimIndex], but this hasn't changed the output. @Bulkin

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have figured it out! There are two issues that were occurring: First and foremost, I had a confusion about how .add(), .remove(), and .save() work in tandem. The fundamental problem is that each player's runes collection was  a **one-to-many** association with the various card records, and I was calling .add() and .remove() on two different players' runes collections and moving the same card with both calls. This doesn't work because both of those collections are associated via the **same foreign key** on the card record. What I didn't understand is that what .remove() actually **does** is cue up a cb (that is fired when .save() is called) that goes to the associated (the card) record and **deletes the foreign key to the record (the player) in whose collection the removed record (the card) resides**. This means that my .add() call was being overwritten by my .remove() call, because .add() was instantiating a foreign key from the card to the player, and then .remove() was deleting that foreign key, **even though it no longer pointed to the player from whose runes collection I was attempting to remove the card**. The fix is very simple: simply don't call .remove() at all, as using .add() to push the card into one player's runes collection automatically removes it from the other player's runes by overwriting the foreign key.

There was a second, and indirect problem that this brought to my attention, however, which is that a record returned inside a .save() callback is **not always consistent with the changes made to the database**. I believe that the issue was that .save() was returning a populated player record that matched what we would expect the database to look like, based on the .add() and .remove() calls, but it was failing to take into account the faulty logic that I was using, and it therefore returned a record that looked right, even though the database was wrong. Is this what was happening, and should .save() be tweaked to always return exactly what the database has stored?

I have been able to make the record returned by .save() match the database (even when the .add and remove calls overwrite each other), by leveraging promises with Bluebird.js. There is probably a better way to do it, but I make a new promise for each .find(), return the found record when the promise fulfills, use a Promise.all() to wait for all records to be found before continuing with the logic, then use a .spread() to perform all the saves, and wait for them to return before calling the publishUpdate. It seems that noone else has had my foolish problem, so this pattern may not prove helpful to anyone, else, but I'm closing the issue now that it seems to be all figured out!